# Как выводить значения в output при нажатии на элемент js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть "счётная доска":

[image: Счётная доска]

Нужно, чтобы выводились значения в поля по нажатию на фишки.
Слева, значение набранное на каждой спице. Сверху - результат (сумма набранных фишек на каждой спице).
При повторном нажатии на фишки нужно обнулить поля.
Пыталась сделать по примеру калькулятора, но не получается то, что нужно..

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const rows = container.querySelectorAll('.row');

rows.forEach(r => r.querySelectorAll('.fishka').forEach((el, i) => el.dataset.index = i));

container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const target = e.target;

  if (!target.classList.contains('fishka')) return;

  const row = target.parentNode;
  const currentIndex = Number(target.dataset.index);
  const isLeft = target.classList.contains('left');
  const moveElements = [target];
  const [direction, limit] = isLeft ? [1, row.children.length] : [-1, -1];

  for (let i = currentIndex + direction; i !== limit; i += direction) {
    const el = row.children[i];

    if (el.classList.contains('left') === isLeft) {
      moveElements.push(el);
      continue;
    }

    break;
  }

  for (const el of moveElements) el.classList.toggle('left', !isLeft);
});
```

```css
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #777;

}

section {
    padding-top: 113px;
}

.container {
 align-items: flex-end;
 flex-direction: column;
    width: 781.13px;
    height: 933.96px;
    /*позиционирование по центру*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: center;
    display: block;
}

.pole{
    background: url('../img/1.svg') no-repeat center top / cover;
    width: 900px;
    height: 1052.83px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
position: relative;
margin-top: -50px;
}

.row {
margin-top: -10px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.fishka{
overflow: auto;

}

.fishka:hover {
cursor: grabbing;
}

.left {
  transform: translateX(-260px);
}

.menu{
    top: -80px;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
justify-content: center;
overflow: auto;
}

.sum{
    box-sizing: border-box;
width: 511px;
height: 64px;
background: #DAB26A;
border: 3px solid #96683B;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px #96683B;
border-radius: 20px;

text-align: center;
font-family: 'Roboto';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 48px;
line-height: 56px;
color: #F9F9F9;
}

button {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.result{
    float: left;
    display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;

}

.outputs {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 69px;
    height: 64px;
    background: #DAB26A;
    border: 3px solid #96683B;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;

font-family: 'Roboto';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 48px;
line-height: 56px;
text-align: center;

color: #F9F9F9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.."></script>
</head>
<body>

<section id="menu" class="menu">

<output name="result" class="sum"></output>

<button><img src="img/обновить.svg" alt="Кнопка сброса" id="btnup"></button>

</section>

<section class="result">

<output name="spica_1" value="" class="outputs" id="spica_1"></output>
<output name="spica_2" value="" class="outputs" id="spica_2"></output>

</section>

  <section id="pole" class="pole">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
  </div>

<div class="row">
<img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
<img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
<img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
<img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
<img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
<img src="img/тёмная.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
<img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
<img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
<img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
<img src="img/светлая.svg" alt="fishka" class="fishka">
</div>

    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте data-атрибуты для каждой строки счётной доски. Так мы можем установить множитель (вес разряда), а также атрибут для количества костяшек. Соответственно, сумма по строке будет перемножением этих атрибутов. Общий итог вычисляем как сумма рассчитанных значений по каждой строке.

В примере ниже я использовал flex для строк, включая возможность группировки через "margin-left: auto" для разделения костяшек, и data-атрибуты:

```js
let rows = document.querySelector('.rows');

rows.onclick = e => {
  let tar = e.target;

  if (tar.classList.contains('fishka')) {
    let row = tar.closest('.row');
    let sep = row.querySelector('.separator');

    let taken = +row.dataset.taken;
    let index = +tar.dataset.idx;

    if (sep) sep.classList.remove('separator');
    let newIdx = index + (index >= taken);
    let newSep = row.querySelector(`.fishka[data-idx="${newIdx}"]`);
    if (newSep) newSep.classList.add('separator');
    row.dataset.taken = newIdx;

    calcRowSum(row);
  }
}

function calcRowSum(row) {
  let output = row.previousElementSibling;
  output.value = row.dataset.taken * row.dataset.mult;
  calcTotal();
}

function calcTotal() {
  let rowSums = [...document.querySelectorAll('.row-sum')];
  total.value = rowSums.reduce((a, v) => +v.value + a, 0);
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  gap: 10px;
}

.fishka {
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.separator {
  margin-left: auto;
}

#total {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <output name="total" id="total">0</output>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="rows">
  <output class="row-sum">0</output>
  <div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="10">
    <div class="fishka separator" data-idx="0"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="1"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="2"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="3"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="4"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="5"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="6"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="7"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="8"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="9"></div>
  </div>

  <output class="row-sum">0</output>
  <div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="1">
    <div class="fishka separator" data-idx="0"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="1"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="2"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="3"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="4"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="5"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="6"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="7"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="8"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="9"></div>
  </div>

  <output class="row-sum">0</output>
  <div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="0.25">
    <div class="fishka separator" data-idx="0"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="1"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="2"></div>
    <div class="fishka" data-idx="3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! То, что нужно!))